# How to visually scrape text from web browser window without interacting with remote server or source code?

Tags: web-scraping

How can I continuously and automatically grab text displayed on a loaded web page that's updated automatically hundreds of times daily? Is there a PC app that can continuously "look" for text changes on a browser window and save those changes to a text file?

Interacting with the remote server in any way, shape or form is forbidden and 100% out of the question.

[image]

Comment: Intriguing problem. with the live updating page loaded in a web browser, you could establish a mutation observer on the relevant nodes (by entering js commands in the browser-tools console) and have the text content console-logged each time it's updated. To save the data, you'd probably need to save the messages to file (copy-paste or ctrl-click save) and perhaps clean out superfluous messages with a command line tool such as sed or awk. It's past my bed time to experiment tonight but I'll look back tomorrow if it's not solved by then. good luck

Comment: Add target URL and we can try it and some code if you have.

Answer (score 1):

Without access to your specific page, I can't offer a fully tested solution but instead provide an answer based on experiments on an alternative live page that worked satisfactorily.

This is a fairly detailed answer as felt it was worth giving a  general approach that is adaptable to retrieving live data through the web browser. I've also added some discussion that may help you adapt the approach to your specific problem.

### Detecting changing text on a live web page

Changes to the DOM tree, including those involving text being updated, can be detected using *mutation observers*.

Javascript mutation observers run on the client web browser and require no interaction with the server; they monitor parts of the DOM tree specified when they are set up. In the case of a live updating web page, such as a table displaying changing share prices, data can be recorded by establishing mutation observers for text in the relevant html elements by typing suitable js in the browser developer tools console.

The collected data can, after some period, be saved to file either by copy-paste from the console messages, or by saving the console messages from a menu option (in Firefox for example, control-click opens a context menu with a save option).

### The Anatomy of Mutation Observers

(see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/MutationObserver and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

Several components are required to establish a mutation observer:

1. **A reference to the html element(s)** to be monitored. This is made in the usual way with `targetElement = document.getElementById("<elementID>")` or `targetElement = document.querySelector("<uniqueSelector>")` etc.
2. **A paramter config object** specifying which properties of the mutation will be available to the observer's call-back function.

The contents of the config object depend on what mutations are to be observed and could look something like this:

```
const config = {
  characterData: true, 
  attributes: false, 
  childList: true,
  subtree: false
}
```

Since you will fish out text from element(s) specified in 1) above, you only need to make sure the config data is sufficient to trigger mutation detection. `const config = {childList: true}` was sufficient (but required) in my trial example (see below) but you may have to experiment.

3. **A call-back function** to be executed when a mutation is observed. Usually, the call-back would include a `forEach` loop to process each mutation attribute but in your case it simply needs to include code to report the required data to the console.
4. **An instance of a `MutationObserver`** object needs to be created with a single argument specifying a call-back function to which the Mutation object will be sent when a change is detected (step 3, above). The required syntax is `const observerName = new MutationObserver(call-back);`.
5. **A call to the `observe` method of the `MutationObserver` object instance** you created in 4) is required to begin the monitoring. The call should be made after the items dealt with in 1) to 4) are established. The method call takes two arguments - the target element reference created in 1), and the config object created in 2):

```
observerName.observe(targetElement, config);
```

### An Example of Retrieving Live-Updated Data using a Mutation Observer

Not having access to the web page you wish to scrape, I used an online digital clock as an example of frequently updated data to test the steps suggested above. The clock used is at: http://time-time.net/timer/digital-clock.php

Once the page was loaded in the web browser, I build the JS code required to establish the mutation observer. I did this in a text editor as the the browser console is not always easy for multi-line code. I repeated several cycles of pasting the code from the text editor to the browser console as I developed the code, taking account of errors and failures. Each trial requires a page re-load in the browser as errors occur if declarations are repeated.

The steps 1) to 5) described above were followed:

**Obtain unique IDs for relevant data fields**. I used the browser developer tools to `inspect` the element that I want to record. In my case it was a single field displaying the time. It had a unique ID (`timenow`) and was used to make the required reference to the element using:

```
const targetElement = document.getElementById('timenow');
```

This completed step 1 above. You may need several references (see notes in the *Considerations for Table Data* section below).

**define the config object** described in step 2 above.  In my case, this worked:

```
const config = {
  childList: true
}
```

**Define the call-back function** (step 3). For the single field in my example, this simply involved logging the `innerText` of the target element to the console:

```
const action = (mutations) => {
    console.log(targetElement.innerText);
} // end action function;
```

See notes in the *Considerations for Table Data* section below regarding reporting several data fields.

**Create the `MutationObserver` instance** (step 4):

```
const observer = new MutationObserver(action);
```

Note the argument is the name of the call back function from step 3.

**Invoke the `.observe` method of the Observer object** (step 5):

```
observer.observe(targetElement, config);
```

This is the final working code that I pasted into the developer tools console to begin collecting data:

```
const targetElement = document.getElementById('timenow'); // the target element;

const config = {
  childList: true
}

const action = (mutations) => {
    console.log(targetElement.innerText);
} // end action function;

const observer = new MutationObserver(action);
observer.observe(targetElement, config);
```

The console then updated with the current time value each time it was updated on the web page, and could be left to accumulate data as long as required.

### Saving and Data Cleansing

The accumulated data was saved to file using the context menu option `Save all Messages to File` (ctrl-click in Firefox, other browsers may vary). The data could also have been copy-pasted to a text file to save it.

[image: Screen shot showing console messages being saved via the browser context menu]

At this stage the data file is somewhat 'contaminated' having a stub of the initial pasted javascript, and browser-added console information that was appended to each data line. This is what the saved raw data looked like after manually deleting the first few lines (which contained the code I'd pasted into the console to begin the process):

```
...
6:24:28 pm 2 debugger eval code:12:13
6:24:29 pm 2 debugger eval code:12:13
6:24:30 pm 2 debugger eval code:12:13
6:24:31 pm 2 debugger eval code:12:13
6:24:32 pm 2 debugger eval code:12:13
6:24:33 pm 2 debugger eval code:12:13
6:24:34 pm 2 debugger eval code:12:13
6:24:35 pm 2 debugger eval code:12:13
6:24:36 pm 2 debugger eval code:12:13
6:24:37 pm 2 debugger eval code:12:13
6:24:38 pm 2 debugger eval code:12:13
...
```

Of this, the required data were in the first two white-space-separated columns (the time string and 'pm'). The data was cleansed simply using the command line `awk` tool. In Terminal, the following line opened the `savedData.txt` file and saved just the first two colums to a new file named `cleanData.txt`:

```
$ awk `{print $1" "$2}` savedData.txt > cleanData.txt;
```

This prints the first and second white-space-separated column data for each row to the new file. See https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/linux-shell-scripting/9781782162742/ch04s10.html for simple cases of filtering with awk.

The final file `cleanData.txt` contains data like this:

```
...
6:24:28 pm 
6:24:29 pm 
6:24:30 pm 
6:24:31 pm 
6:24:32 pm 
6:24:33 pm 
6:24:34 pm 
6:24:35 pm 
6:24:36 pm 
6:24:37 pm 
6:24:38 pm 
...
```

### Considerations for Table Data

You will need to adapt the approach and method described above to your particular data. The main difference will be that you may want to save several pieces of data (adjacent cells in the table row) each time one or more of them is updated.

The following are some thoughts on how to approach the adaptation.

Determine the markup used for the table by examining the page source. Your aim is to construct a specific, but as simple as possible, reference to the data as possible.

For example, if the red-boxed data in your question is row one of the table body, you might make a reference as follows:

```
const requiredRow = document.getElementById(<tableid>).getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].getElementsByTagName('tr')[0];
```

where the first row of the `tbody` tag inside a table with the specific `id` is retrieved. You might be lucky and your specific table tow may have its own id that can be used to more directly reference it. It's difficult to predict the markup used for the table but the aim is to create a unique reference to the required row.

Once obtained, the row makes a good target for the mutation observer as any change within any cell will be covered. If you only want to monitor when a share price changes, you could target the cell containing the share price by adding another level to the element reference, e.g.  `....getElementsByTagName('td')[2]` if the third cell (td collection member [2]) contains the share price. Similarly, you could chose to report only when the time is updated so could target the time cell.

For the call-back function, decide which cells to output. If you want all the cells in the row, the code might be:

```
const action = (mutations) => {
    const cells = requiredRow.getElementsByTagName('td')
    console.log(cells[0].innerText, cells[1].innerText, cells[2].innerText, cells[3].innerText, cells[4].innerText);
} // end action function;
```

Note that a single console log was made in order to keep each data item on one line for that change (this makes iterating over the cells collection tricky and so it's easier to reference each element by index, [0]-[5] in this case. This alsogives you flexibility if you want to leave out some cells or change the order).

For the final data clean up using awk, you would modify the print fields to suit the cells you want, e.g.

```
$ awk `{print $1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5"}` savedData.txt > cleanData.txt;
```

Note the field indexes for awk begin with 1, not 0 as for a javascript array or html collection. The " " is to insert a space between each output field. Awk is very versatile and allows you to specify field separtors other than white space for both input and output.

If you need help applying this method to your particular problem, post details of the areas causing problems and I'll try and help. If making references to the target elements proves difficult, it would help if you can post html for the area of the table where your data row is located.